# Can't load sites, even admins

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-enterprise, access-denied

I created a site, but I can't get to it. Anytime I try, it tells me to request permission, but I can't get any of my admin accounts into the site to approve them. Even on the server, when I try to switch from central admin to the site, it asks me to log in and after three attempts, just goes to a blank screen. I've recreated the site twice, but it does the same thing every time, with all of the site collections on the site. Any ideas?

Comment: Can you please tag the SharePoint version. Is this behavior only for your account?

Comment: Tagged, it is 2013. And no. I have added three accounts as admins (two as farm admins and site collection admins) and two test accounts as general users. All exhibit the same behavior: a request to join page.

Comment: Can you explain how you created the site collection? Who you added as the Site Collection Admin? Are you able to access the webapplication?

Comment: I created it through central administration. I've added myself and the service account that I used to create everything. And the web application does the same thing. Just asks to request access. I can get to the settings through central administration, but as soon as I click on site or navigate to the site, I get the same behavior.

Comment: Check this https://www.dmcinfo.com/latest-thinking/blog/id/8565/sharepoint-2013-access-denied-to-root-site-of-web-application

Comment: is it publishing site and did you configure the Object Cache? if object cache not configured properly then everybdy get access denied....http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff758656(v=office.15).aspx

Comment: I found that earlier today and tried the script that was in the comments (which didn't work) but actually doing what the article suggested fixed my issue!! Who knew a brand new install could corrupt so quickly....thank you!!

Comment: (For an edit, I didn't see Waqas' reply before I posted this. It ended up being a corrupted authentication setting as per Amal's suggestion.)

Answer (score 0):

Increase you log settings to verbose.  Check server and ULS logs. Look for patterns around specific paths or artifacts getting denied.  Also be on the look out for distributed cache references.

I also recommend using fiddler which can tell which requests are being denied.

In the event it looks like certain system artifacts are getting denied re-run you configuration wizard or reset security via powershell.  If its cache related you may need to try restarting that service.

If resetting permissions don't work you may need to get more granular and double check SQL and local security groups and ensure the proper accounts are set up.

I would also look at clearing the configuration cache on the server.